# Set a property to JS function's prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype-chain

I create function and add property in its prototype as following

```
let F = function(){}
 F.prototype.foo = 'abc'
```

My question is why it will return undefined when using the F.foo?
But after using this

```js
let F = function() {}
F.prototype.foo = 'abc'
let fn = new F()
console.log(fn.foo) // return 'abc'
```

Comment: Because `F.prototype.foo` is not the same as `F.foo`. When you create F using `fn = new F()` the object created `fn` has the properties of its prototype `F.prototype`

Answer (score 1):

`foo` is a property of the *prototype object*, one which instances have an internal prototype of when instantiated. This is not the same thing as the *constructor function*, which is completely different.

When you *call* the constructor function, you get an instance in return, but the constructor is not an instance or the instance's prototype.

This is how the prototype chain works here:

```
Object.prototype -> Function.prototype -> F

Object.prototype -> F.prototype -> fn
```

When you set something on `F.prototype`, it's nowhere on F's *internal prototype* chain - it's only on the prototype chain of *instances*.

If you set something on `Object.prototype`, both `F` and the `fn` instance would inherit it:

```js
let F = function() {}
Object.prototype.foo = 'abc'
let fn = new F()
console.log(fn.foo) // return 'abc'
console.log(F.foo);
```

This works because `Object.prototype` is within both of their prototype chains.

(But that's just to give you an idea of how things work - in actual code, you should not mutate `Object.prototype`)